# Undefined offset while importing CSV with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Situation:
Array index is right.
And **dd($row[5])** shows me "email address" from a record - work fine.

However on assigning it **($row[5])** to email field of the object, Laravel shows: **ErrorException - Undefined offset: 5**

Here is my code:

```
$file = $request->file('file');
$csvData = file_get_contents($file);
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', explode("\n", $csvData));

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    //dd($row[5]); // shows me email
    $subscriber = new Subscriber;
    $subscriber->email = $row[5]; // Shows: ErrorException - Undefined offset: 5
    $subscriber->first_name = $row[3];
    $subscriber->save();
}
```

Here's **ddd($row);**

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2019-02-27 01:01:52"
  2 => "mailchimp"
  3 => "Name"
  4 => "Lastname"
  5 => "fake-subscriber@gmail.com"
  6 => "EN"
]
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: I think there are some line without index 5. You use `dd()` only print first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `dd()` will print message. and `exit()`, so you just print at first loop. It can be without index 5 at second loop.
2. Don't `save()` records in each loop, that take more cost times in db; Try to put them in array, and insert them at once.
3. If you don't want to save that records without email just check the row and don't put it in array.

*PS: If you want to rollback when one record failed, try to use `transaction`*

Your code would like this:

```php
$file = $request->file('file');
$csvData = file_get_contents($file);
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', explode("\n", $csvData));

$arr = array();
// dd($row)  // Here you can see the rows which without index 5.
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $sub = [];
    $sub['email'] = isset($row[5])? $row[5]: ''; 
    $sub['first_name'] = isset($row[3])? $row[3]: '';
    $arr []= $sub;
}
Subscriber::insert($arr);
```

Or

```php
$arr = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $sub = [];
    if (count($row) > 5) {
            $sub['email'] = $row[5]; 
            $sub['first_name'] = $row[3];
            $arr []= $sub;
    }
}
Subscriber::insert($arr);
```

Comment: Can i remove the line `$arr []= $sub;` and change the last line to `Subscriber::insert($sub);`?

Comment: @Vadim No, that will insert sql at every loop

Comment: It should not insert at every loop if `Subscriber::insert($sub);` is outside the loop. Or i missing something here?

Comment: @Vadim Put it outside, and insert `array`, this will change to one mysql query: `insert into table (email, name) values (sub1_email, sub1_name), (sub2_email, sub2_name), `